# Why does using renderPrint() in combination with a .csv file read by read_csv2 produce a strange indexing bar in my output?

Tags: r, shiny, readr

I have a problem when I use `renderPrint()` in combination with a `.csv` file uploaded by the user and read by `read_csv2()`. I always get a strange kind of indexing bar before the actual output.

When I replace `read_csv2()` with base R's `read.csv2()` the indexing bar disappears. Therefore, my guess is that the problem is somehow related to the fact that `read_csv2()` reads the `.csv` file as `tibble` and not as `data.frame`.
Alternatively, I also tried `vroom::vroom()`, but the problem with the progress bar still remains.

In my app I would like to use either `read_csv2()` or `vroom::vroom()` as they are both noticeably faster than `read.csv2()`.

My reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(
    inputId = "upload",
    label = "Upload file:"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    read_csv2(input$upload$datapath)
  })

  output$text <-
    renderPrint({
      class(data())
    })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output in Shiny app:

```
indexing 0.csv [============================================================================================] ?, eta:  0s
                                                                                                                         
[1] "spec_tbl_df" "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress bar is shown by `readr` package by default. You can disable them using `options`.

```
options(readr.show_progress = FALSE)
```